# ubuntu gitkraken unable to access var

Tags: ubuntu, gitkraken

I am trying to use ubuntu for php laravel project, I have setup all the requirements but now I am facing problem with gitkraken. I am trying to clone repo on var/www/html but I cant even enter in var folder please help
[image]

Comment: posting in https://askubuntu.com/ will be interesting.

Comment: Ok I will ask there,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to uninstall this application and install it from the [website](https://www.gitkraken.com/download).. the same happened with me .. for the main reason why this is happening .. you may check this answer [askUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/419610/permission-of-a-desktop-file)

Comment: Just had this problem when installing from a snap. Did not expect this solution to work... but it did. Still relevant a year later for those wondering.

Answer (score 1):

Although the accepted answer is not technically incorrect, it did not actually solve the problem for me when running Ubuntu 18.04.

You need to install the application from the website, but you MUST do so using the command-line like so:

```
wget https://release.gitkraken.com/linux/gitkraken-amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i gitkraken-amd64.deb
```

If you try to install it by just double-clicking the .deb file in your home directory, it will not work as snap does some funky things with it.